# Error 500 for /Sign_in and /Sign_up Devise routes with rails on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have got a problem, I have changed the routes to sign_in, sign_up and sign_out on devise. Every thing works smoothly on local. But in production, I got an error 500.

I have restarted the app, updated the database... Do someone has an Idea?

Here is the logs:

```
at=info method=GET path="/sign_out" host=www.domain.com request_id=84424ae1-e917-48d5-b54f-dd18c1862481 fwd="82.251.30.15" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=500 bytes=1093 protocol=http
2018-06-19T11:41:14.232886+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-06-19T11:41:14.232785 #4]  INFO -- : [84424ae1-e917-48d5-b54f-dd18c1862481] Started GET "/sign_out" for 82.251.30.15 at 2018-06-19 11:41:14 +0000
2018-06-19T11:41:14.234261+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-06-19T11:41:14.234163 #4]  INFO -- : [84424ae1-e917-48d5-b54f-dd18c1862481] Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
2018-06-19T11:41:14.235848+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-06-19T11:41:14.235786 #4]  INFO -- : [84424ae1-e917-48d5-b54f-dd18c1862481] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2018-06-19T11:41:14.236922+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-06-19T11:41:14.236858 #4] FATAL -- : [84424ae1-e917-48d5-b54f-dd18c1862481]
2018-06-19T11:41:14.236995+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-06-19T11:41:14.236944 #4] FATAL -- : [84424ae1-e917-48d5-b54f-dd18c1862481] NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
2018-06-19T11:41:14.237037+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-06-19T11:41:14.236992 #4] FATAL -- : [84424ae1-e917-48d5-b54f-dd18c1862481]
2018-06-19T11:41:14.237130+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-06-19T11:41:14.237060 #4] FATAL -- : [84424ae1-e917-48d5-b54f-dd18c1862481] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:44:in `resource_name'
2018-06-19T11:41:14.237132+00:00 app[web.1]: [84424ae1-e917-48d5-b54f-dd18c1862481] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.3/app/controllers/dev
```

Comment: How did you change the routes?

Comment: its taking `path="/sign_out"` as get method, it should be delete. Also check that this is in your application.js:

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

Comment: I did the route like this:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your interest !

```
I did the route like this: devise_scope :user do
    get "/sign_in" => "devise/sessions#new", as: "new_user_session" # custom path to login/sign_in
    post "/sign_in" => "devise/sessions#create", as: "user_session" # custom path to login/sign_in
    get "/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", as: "destroy_user_session"
    get "/B21zukt938lama272kutoni" => "devise/registrations#new", as: "new_user_registration" # custom path to sign_up/registration
    post "/B21zukt938lama272kutoni" => "devise/registrations#create", as: "user_registration" # custom path to login/sign_in
  end
```